# My Family settings prevent app downloading

Tags: settings, parental-control

I have an issue with my first Windows Phone device.  When trying to download an app from the marketplace I get this message:

> The My Family settings for your account prevent you from downloading this item.  Your parent can manage My Family settings at windowsphone.com

When I go try to manage My Family settings at windowsphone.com, it shows me the Get Started link, but I don't have any accounts hooked up to it.

I think the problem is that I started to download a trial of Kinectimals and handed the phone off to my daughter, who was prompted for a birthdate. I thought it was asking for a birthdate as part of the game, and told her to input her own birthday. So now my windowsphone account thinks I'm 7 years old and I can't find any way to update that.

Comment: thanks for this post. i did something very similar and was beating my head against the wall trying to figure this out.

Comment: I stumbled on the same problem on my new Windows Phone 8 device. The default setting was today's date, and without thinking further about I just tapped OK. There was nothing there describing the severe implications of an incorrect date, on the contrary, the default was set to today. Now I cannot even install a pdf-viewer! :) Strange thing is, I can change my birth date on the live.com account I had to register, but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 6):

I got the answer from Microsoft directly - there is no way to change the birthdate associated with a store account.  Apparently Microsoft can't or won't help you with it either.

I had to delete my account, reset my phone, and create a new account!!!

Comment: Did you contact them via email or phone? In my experience they can do things over the phone which they claim they cannot online e.g. change your account's country.

Comment: You should have had your mother do this for you. :P

Comment: At present you can change your birthdate associated with your Microsoft account.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I had the same issue setting up my sisters phone. To fix the problem log onto your live account at www.live.com go to your account settings (not your profile settings) then change the d.o.b to the correct one. My sisters was showing she was born in 2000, where in reality she was born in 1982. A quick change of the details and the app store worked correctly.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to https://account.microsoft.com/
2. Login with your Microsoft account
3. Click on *Your Info* tab
   [image]
4. Click on *Edit your personal info*
   [image]
5. Change your Date of Birth and click save.

Your account details will be updated across all MS services.

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot and tried many times to change the date, but I was still unable to download apps. So I went to *menu>settings>about>reset your phone* and then I opened a new Microsoft Account (Hotmail) and I made the year of birth 1970. I tried it on my Windows Phone 8 (HTC 8S) and it worked. Hope that helps :)!