# Setting up MS Account to download apps on my WP

Tags: 8.0, microsoft-account

I bought a new Windows Phone 8 and it says that I have to set up an account to download apps since I am 14 years old and I don't have anyone in my family who has a Windows Phone. So what can I do? I really would like some apps on my phone before I try returning it and get a new phone.

I have tried to setup a account myself but it wont let me download game still even if it says my account was created. I would really like to understand why I cant download any games or Facebook. Does anyone else have this problem or is it just me?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1154/106

Comment: Your parents don't need a Windows Phone for that, but they do need a Microsoft Account where they can add you as a child and allow you to download apps.

Answer (score 1):

As @Thomas suggested, your parents need to create a Microsoft Account where they can add you as a child and allow you to download apps.

Check this link for more info on how do do it:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/family-safety?woldogcb=0