# Windows Store My Family issue

Tags: store, parental-control, lumia-435

I've had a windows phone for nearly a year, and in all this time haven't been able to get the app store to work. It always says my family needs updating, despite me being registered on there as an adult, twice. It's very frustrating having a smart phone which can't get apps. I'd appreciate any answers. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1154/106

Comment: Take a look at this answer - http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/13116/18061