# Adult in My Family can't download apps on Windows Phone?

Tags: nokia-lumia-535, microsoft-account, parental-control

I am the only person in my Family and I am an Adult in It.
Even then My Windows Phone Won't download any App.
I can download it on my Windows 10 laptop.

Nokia Lumia 535.

PS:I Also Did add another adult ,But this isn't fixed yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1154/106