# can't download WhatsApp

Tags: store

In my phone what's app can't download.it needs my family setup .i don't know how to set up my family in my Lumia 535 .without my family setup my mobile is not download WhatsApp.

Comment: Are you on 8.1 or 10?

Comment: This question may have an answer here [My Family settings prevent app downloading](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1154/my-family-settings-prevent-app-downloading)