# I Cannot Download X-Box Games !! Needs Parent?

Tags: store, downloads

I Cannot download my favorite game because the system needs a parental email or account ! I hate it !! Can you just fix it to flow faster as I download ??

Comment: You may find your answer here - [My Family settings prevent app downloading](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1154/my-family-settings-prevent-app-downloading)

Answer (score 0):

jacob

The most likely reason you are unable to do this is that there are parental controls on your Microsoft account if you have an Xbox  get your parent to alter the limitation through there if not this error should not be happening and go with your parents to get is looked at. The reason you are able to download other apps is because those arent through your Xbox and your restriction needs to be removed/altered through there.

Hope this helps,

~Ashton