# how do i do to download me some apps without arranging the family?

Tags: lumia, apps, microsoft-account, xbox-live, downloads

[image: this is the word that pop up when i click a download button on my window store or xbox]how to arrange this? because i cant download some application on my phone.
please help me.

Comment: You could find your answer here [My Family settings prevent app downloading](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1154/my-family-settings-prevent-app-downloading)