# remove the my family set up needed setting

Tags: microsoft-account, parental-control

My Microsoft Mobile in given the my family set up needed setting ' my Microsoft mobile does not have this .please remove the my family set up needed setting?
Thanks

Comment: This won't be needed if you are grater than 18 years. Change your date of birth by following these steps here - http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/13116/18061