# Family required to download apps on Windows Phone

Tags: apps, parental-control

So I just got this Windows Phone from my brother, who got it from his girlfriends but I can't download any apps. It keeps telling me to set up *My Family* before I can download anything like Twitter or Instagram, but when I made the *My Family* account and hooked up my e-mail to it, I still couldn't find a way to connect it to my phone so I can download apps.

Comment: Brower on and search windowsphone.com/family on their computer

Comment: Have you signed in using your microsoft account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Family settings prevent app downloading](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1154/my-family-settings-prevent-app-downloading)